# Using WinUSB with USB Device Simulator

Tags: visual-c++, winusb

I am working on USB client app and would like to use WinUSB functions to read and write to USB channel. I also would like to use provided with WinDDK usbsamp driver and SoftUSBLoopback.dll to implement the simulated end of the USB device.
I have followed instructions (**WinUSB (Winusb.sys**) Installation) to update usbsamp “Intel 82930 USB Test Board” driver (usbsamp.sys) to WinUSB (winusb.sys) driver so I could use it in my client app. I have modified my inf file (provided below), and update completes successfully but then when I call WinUsb_Initialize – it always returns 0.
Regards,
Janusz

```
;
;
; Installs WinUsb
;

[Version]
Signature = "$Windows NT$"
Class     = USBDevice
ClassGUID = {88BAE032-5A81-49f0-BC3D-A4FF138216D6}
Provider  = %ManufacturerName%
CatalogFile = WinUSBInstallation.cat
DriverVer=04/16/2013,13.54.20.543

; ========== Manufacturer/Models sections ===========

[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName% = Microsoft,NTAMD64

[Standard.NTamd64]
%DeviceName% =USB_Install, USB\VID_045E&PID_930A   ; Intel 82930

; For XP and later
[Microsoft.NTAMD64]
%DeviceName%=USB_Install, USB\VID_045E&PID_930A   ; Intel 82930
; ========== Class definition ===========

[ClassInstall32]
AddReg = ClassInstall_AddReg

[ClassInstall_AddReg]
HKR,,,,%ClassName%
HKR,,NoInstallClass,,1
HKR,,IconPath,%REG_MULTI_SZ%,"%systemroot%\system32\setupapi.dll,-20"
HKR,,LowerLogoVersion,,5.2

; =================== Installation ===================

[USB_Install]
Include = winusb.inf
Needs   = WINUSB.NT

[USB_Install.Services]
Include =winusb.inf
Needs   = WINUSB.NT.Services

[USB_Install.HW]
AddReg=Dev_AddReg

[Dev_AddReg]
HKR,,DeviceInterfaceGUIDs,0x10000,"{00873fdf-61a8-11d1-aa5e-00c04fb1728b}"

; [DestinationDirs]
; If your INF needs to copy files, you must not use the DefaultDestDir directive here.  
; You must explicitly reference all file-list-section names in this section.

; =================== Strings ===================

[Strings]
ManufacturerName            = "Microsoft"
ClassName                   = "Sample Device"
DeviceName                  ="Fx2 Learning Kit Device"
REG_MULTI_SZ

            = 0x00010000
```

Comment: What is your doubt? Is the winusb.sys installing correctly? Where is your `WinUsb_Initialize` function?

Comment: Yes, please provide the code you are using to open the device. Keep in mind that WinUSB requires two steps to do this: one to open a handle to the USB device, using it's hardware ID, via CreateFile(); the second is using that handle in the DeviceHandle argument in WinUsb_Initialize(). Then you will get a valid WINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE to use throughout the rest of your application.